# background-image in iphone safari not showing up properly

Tags: iphone, css, safari

I have a website that I can't get to view properly on the iPhone. The website in question is [this](http://www.capital-restaurants.com) and this is how it shows on iPhone:

[image]

You can replicate the same behavior by narrowing down the left or right side of the browser. Once you have even the smallest horizontal scroll you will see that the black background shrinks.

The problem is the `main` property:

```
.main {
    background: url("images/bg1-1.png") repeat-y scroll center top transparent;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
}
```

More precisely the `bg1-1.png` image that's 1043x14 pixels and it's not repeating as it should and I can't understand why. What I am missing?

Comment: I can't figure out what the problem is. What black background?

Comment: Take a look at the website as it is on any browser and then at the screenshot taken with the iPhone. The center part where's all the text has a black transparent background (the bg1-1.png image) which shows ok in any normal browser but not on the iPhone. Also, you can replicate the same behavior of the website if you narrow down the left or right side of the browser window so that you'll have to scroll horizontal. In both cases you can see that the black transparent background / image doesn't adjust properly.

Comment: I know this isn't relevant to the original question, but since I can't comment yet I have to post here. I looked at your website and I would highly suggest compressing your images. They take a very long time to load. This is especially important for mobile applications and people who may have a slower connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that it is set to `width: 100%` which makes the `div.main` scale  to be smaller than the rest of the site. You need to set it to be a fixed width so that it doesn't shrink like that.

Comment: Thanks, solved it with `@media screen and (max-width: 1024px){ div.main {width: 1000px;}}`

Comment: You're welcome! Glad I could help :). An aside, I would caution you against WordPress lately. I do a lot of WordPress at my current job and we have been having lots of issues with plugins being hacked, which is a huge pain to fix if you aren't familiar with how hackers inject using javascript security issues.